# Using List<T> causes second Page Load in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, generic-list, pageload

I have a fairly simple web application that gets a list of items from a database (in a DataTable), and binds a view of that DataTable to a Repeater.

When converting my DataTable to a List (which is done in a class library), Page Load fires a second time! Walking though the debugger, the same items are in the list that were in the DataTable.

The only code in my page was:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptOffers.DataSource = DataAccess.GetOfferList(offerId); // returns List<T>
            rptOffers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public static List<OfferItem> GetOfferList(int offerId)
    {
        DataTable dtOffers = GetOfferData(offerId);
        List<OfferItem> offers = new List<OfferItem>();

        // loop throw all of the offers
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtOffers.Rows)
        {
            // add each offer to the List<>
            OfferItem currentOffer = new OfferItem();

            // initialize the OfferItem properties...

            offers.Add(currentOffer);
        }

        return offers;
    }
```

When I change it back to this, it works fine:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptOffers.DataSource = DataAccess.GetOfferItems(offerId);
            rptOffers.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else I need to do in my List to keep it from running Page Load again?

Comment: You sure you aren't submitting the page twice or something?

Comment: You may want to post the code for "GetOfferList"  - however I don't see any reason why it would cause a postback.

Comment: Jack, that's why I left it out, but I added to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this issue when AutoEventWireup is set to true in my .aspx file

```
    <%@ ... AutoEventWireup="True" ...  %>
```

and my InitializeComponent function still contains a hookup for Page_Load

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {  
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually did a search and found that out, but I don't have the InitializeComponent method.